# Can Windows 8 RT applications change the color temperature of your screen (a la f.lux)?

Tags: display, windows-8, display-settings

I use a program called [f.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) to change the color temperature of my screen at night. This makes it easier to look at, and supposedly helps with consistent sleep patterns. You can find several similar applications around the internet.

Are Windows 8 RT applications allowed to change the color temperature of your screen? Even if there are not yet any apps that do this, I would like to know if it is possible.

Comment: If you're asking from a programming standpoint, this question would be better suited to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Karan: My standpoint is kind of mixed: I want to know as a user whether this kind of thing is possible in Windows 8. I'm not planning on coding it myself, but as a user I'm interested in knowing whether there will eventually be apps like this available.

Comment: But the thing is, this can only be answered from a programming perspective, by those familiar with the SDK (refer your own comment below). So why not simply ask over there if the SDK allows it, and if so, how? (You can ignore the latter half of the answers if you wish.) You can bet that if it is allowed, someone will get around to implementing it in an app eventually.

Comment: @Karan: That sounds reasonable. I am still a little uncertain about which site is most appropriate, so I will wait for more discussion here before asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything BUILT-IN that can do this in RT, but I imagine if the SDK allows it, someone will create something to accomplish it fairly quickly.

Comment: This is my question: Does the SDK allow it? My understanding is that in general Windows RT apps are more limited than x86 apps.

Comment: I'm not sure, as I'm not a programmer. Possibly someone else knows.